# API Design in microservices

Tags: rest, api, microservices

I am designing a Microservice application but have some difficulties with the REST API design.

Scenario: A Microservice application with the services "Customer" and "Order", and follows the "Database-per-service pattern".

The customer-service have basic endpoints to represent a customer resource like:

`GET /customers`, `POST /customers`, `GET /customers/:id` etc...

Problem: How to design the endpoints for the order-service, to get all orders belonging to a customer?

I've thought about different solutions but none really satisfy me.

1. `/customers/id/orders` - My problem with this solutions is the use of "customers" in a service that does not contain any data about the customers.
2. `/orders?customerid=123` - This would work, but I dont feel that it follows the normal API design guidelines.

Does any guidelines on the subject of API design in microservice architecture exists?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMO, you are requesting for an order so you should ask for the resource order. You are customer has no role to play as orders are not kept inside a customer resources.
If anything, order has a reference to a customer.
And if you are querying orders based on some attribute, they should be passed as a query parameters.
So since you are asking (GET) for resource (Order) and want to filter them (based on customer in query param), the option 2 make sense.
And thats how I would design it and those are my reasons to design it this way.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Anunay. But what if an order has some attachments to it? A normal query would then be /customers/123/orders/321/attachments. With the of the second form (and the one you suggest) It would look something like this: /orders/attatchments?customerid=123&ordersid=321 ?

Comment: it should be /order/{orderid}/attachment/{attachmentid}. Only then we can get attachments, since attachments are within order resource. Now the fact that you have order id when you need not to filter on orders. When you filtering on ordes you reuesting order resource and thats valid. Thats how it goes, but for custom use cases you can opt for custom searching and in that case you might have to get rid of get and move to post

Comment: For the record, it is not me that have downvoted your answer. I will mark it as accepted since this question is a matter of opinion, and you state that your answer is your own opinion.